# Java GUI Moving buttons to bottom of the page

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, layout-manager

I was wondering how I would move my buttons to the bottom of the frame/window.

What I have now is this:

[image]

And what I want it to look like is this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Font;

public class checkbook{
   static JButton Button[] = new JButton[8];
   JLabel begin, accountName, balance;
   JFrame frame;
   JPanel jpanel, jpanel1;
   Container contentPane;
   private JTextField textAccount, textBalance;

   public static void main(String[] args){

      checkbook checkbook = new checkbook();
      checkbook.startFrame();
   }

   checkbook(){
      frame = new JFrame("Checkbook");

   }

   public void startFrame(){

      String bottomButtons[] = {
            "Create a New Account", "Load Trans from a file", "Add New Transactions", "Search Transactions",
            "Sort Transactions", "View/Delete Transactions", "Backup Transactions", "Exit"
         };  

      Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane(); 
      contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      Font beginFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN + Font.BOLD, 22);
      textAccount = new JTextField(" ", 15);
      textBalance = new JTextField("0.0", 15);


      begin = new JLabel("Use The Buttons below To Manage Transactions");
      begin.setFont(beginFont);
      contentPane.add(begin);
     //Container contentPane1 = frame.getContentPane();
     //contentPane1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
      accountName = new JLabel ("Account Name: ");
      jpanel.add(accountName);
      jpanel.add(textAccount);

      balance = new JLabel ("Balance: ");
      jpanel.add(balance);
      jpanel.add(textBalance);

      JPanel jpanel1 = new JPanel();
      jpanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4)); 

      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
         Button[i] = new JButton(bottomButtons[i]);
         jpanel1.add(Button[i]);
         //Button[i].addActionListener(AL);
      }




      frame.pack();
      frame.setSize(800, 300);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true); 
      frame.add(jpanel);
      frame.add(jpanel1);    


   }
}
```

So I was wondering what would I do to move the buttons down to the bottom. Would I have to use a `BorderLayout` and use `BorderLayout.SOUTH` etc or is there a way to do this with the `GridLayout` I already have. If I have to use the `BorderLayout` how would I keep my buttons in order (2 rows, 4 columns).

Comment: What IDE are you using ? And why are you not using the Drag and Drop feature to change the location of buttons.

Comment: @KaranSharma: because then you don't learn about the layout managers and how to use them. Code-generating apps are great, but not until you are well familiar with the underlying GUI library.

Comment: I am using JGrasp, and yes, I am aware that I can use something like Eclipse to just "draw" all I need, but since this is for a semester project I am working on, I'd rather write the code by hand to see how it works. Basically exactly what Hovercraft Full Of Eels said.

Comment: *Sorry if I incorrectly inserted my code, I didn't know how else to insert it **without having to enter 4 spaces in front of each line of code.***  Select the text of the entire code sample and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I have to use a BorderLayout and use BorderLayout.SOUTH

Yes, but the best answer is for you to try it and see what happens. Why don't you?

> If I have to use the BorderLayout how would I keep my buttons in order(2 rows, 4 columns).

Nest JPanels. Put the buttons in a GridLayout using JPanel, and place that JPanel BorderLayout.SOUTH, or better, BorderLayout.PAGE_END

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NestedPanels extends JPanel {
   private static final String TITLE_TEXT = "Use The Buttons Below To Manage Transactions";
   private static final String[] BTN_TEXTS = { "Create a New Account",
         "Load a Trans from a File", "Add New Transactions",
         "Search Transactions", "Sort Transactions",
         "View/Delete Transactions", "Backup Transaction", "Exit" };
   private static final int TITLE_POINTS = 24;

   public NestedPanels() {
      JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE_TEXT, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD,
            TITLE_POINTS));
      JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
      titlePanel.add(titleLabel); // put it in a JPanel so it will expand to fill BoxLayout

      JPanel accountBalancePanel = new JPanel();
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JLabel("Account Name:"));
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JTextField(10));
      accountBalancePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JLabel("Balance:"));
      accountBalancePanel.add(new JTextField(10));

      JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
      northPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(northPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      northPanel.add(titlePanel);
      northPanel.add(accountBalancePanel);

      JPanel southBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4, 1, 1));
      for (String btnText : BTN_TEXTS) {
         southBtnPanel.add(new JButton(btnText));
      }

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(400, 400))); // just an empty placeholder
      add(southBtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      NestedPanels mainPanel = new NestedPanels();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nested Panels Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

Comment: So to clarify, I am going to have to make a JPanel for my gridlayout then ANOTHER JPanel to put the JPanel w/ GridLayout at the bottom.

Comment: At the moment, I am having trouble figuring out how to nest the Jpanels, it seems really easy, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around this concept. Are you able to give me an example?

Comment: @AlternateRealm: for example